# How to specify tint as custom attribute on ImageView when using MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How do I specify a tint color to an imageView as a custom attribute when using MotionLayout. Currently I can only specify a custom background color in my `MotionScene` xml file:

```
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75"
        motion:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" >
        <CustomAttribute
            motion:attributeName="backgroundColor"
            motion:customColorValue="#9999FF" />
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
```

Answer (score 17):

Note that you are using `backgroundColor` but the attribute is `android:background`. For `tint` you should write:

```
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="ColorFilter"
                motion:customColorValue="#9999FF" />
```

As far as I know, the feature of `CustomAttribute` uses reflection and not the attributes from xml etc. Keep that in mind for all custom attributes.

Comment: how to set Visibility in custom attribute

Comment: @JithishPN You can set visibility within the <Constraint ... > just like the other lines for android:layout_width, etc. Type it as: android:visibility="visible"

Comment: Is there a good place to find all the attributeName's? For example, I want to be able to find the different attributeNames like "ColorFilter" for a CardView. You mentioned reflection, does that just mean the getters and setters available in the Java code?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [ColorFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter).

```
<CustomAttribute
    motion:attributeName="colorFilter"
    motion:customColorValue="@color/your_tint_color" />
```

Comment: How to change 'src' of ImageView? (change drawable between state)

Answer (score -4):

Since [tint takes a color value](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:tint), it should be almost identical to `backgroundColor`

`<CustomAttribute
    motion:attributeName="tint"
    motion:customColorValue="@color/your_tint_color" />`

Comment: In order for a custom attribute to work, there has to exist a setter/getter function with the exact same name as the attribute name (getRadius()/setRadius(...)  -> radius). In this case the ImageView class does not have a function like "setTint(int color)". The setTint function from the class only accepts a ColorStateList, but not a simple color value. So this wont work